# How do I compress and extract a JAR file in Visual basic 2010?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, compression

Hello I got a short question
How do I extract a JAR file with visual basic 2010
And how do I compress one?

Comment: First, look up some reference to the "jar format".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself an it is posted at :

http://www.codeproject.com/Answers/549144/Howplusdoplusipluscompressplusandplusextractplusap#answer2

If you have the same problem then you should definitely look at that answer.
Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

A JAR file is a java file, so you can't edit, extract or compile a jar file with visual basic. Visual Basic is made for making .exe files. For Editting Jar files you can use Eclipse or something else. For extracting or compiling just change the file extension to .zip and back to .jar ;)

Een JAR bestand is een java bestand, dus kan je niet niet veranderen in Visual Basic, visual basic is namelijk bedoeld om .exe bestanden te maken. Wat je wel kunt doen is een .jar bestand veranderen in Eclipse of een ander editings programma. Om hem te "compilen" of te "extracten", gewoon de extensie veranderen van .jar naar .zip en weer terug ;)